# C# and Oracle 10g database to call stored procedure

Tags: c#, ado.net, oracle10g, dataset

I am a C# + SQL server database developer.

Now I am using Oracle as a database. I have one Oracle stored procedure retuning ref cursor.

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Get_Trans_Data ( p_return_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS

BEGIN
  OPEN p_return_cur FOR
  select * from test_tbl1 ;
END Get_Trans_Data;
```

---

Using Oledb only how can I access this stored proc and save result in dataset?

I am not get the option for ref cursor datatype in Oledb.

Comment: why are you using OleDB to connect to Oracle? the suggested way is to use the Oracle provided .NET data Provider ODP.NET http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: I have .net framework 3.5 installed on production machine. Considering the load and business of machine client restrict to installed any other software... So I dont have permission to use ODP.NET.

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as "C#.NET". The language is named "C#".

Comment: Thanks John, for correcting me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this. No need to add parameter for OUT's. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973871.aspx)

```
static void Read()
{
    using (var currentConnection = new OleDbConnection(
        "provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=orcl;User ID=db_test;Password=db_test;"))
    {

        currentConnection.Open();
        using (var myCommand = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            myCommand.Connection = currentConnection;
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.CommandText = "Get_Data";

            myCommand.Parameters.Add(
                new OleDbParameter(
                    "firstParam",
                    OleDbType.Integer, 0, ParameterDirection.Input,
                    true, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Default, Convert.DBNull));

            myCommand.Parameters[0].Value = 42;

            var myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myDataReader.Read())
                for (int i = 0; i < myDataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                    Console.WriteLine(myDataReader.GetName(i));
        }
    }
}

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Get_Data (
   p_return_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
   firstParam INTEGER) 
IS 
BEGIN 
  OPEN p_return_cur FOR select * from test; 
END Get_Data;
```